# Which approach is better for discovering container readiness?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes, docker-swarm, service-discovery

This question is discussed many times but I'd like to hear some best practices and real-world examples of using each of the approaches below:

1. Designing containers which are able to check the health of dependent services. Simple script [whait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) can be usefull for this kind of developing containers, but aren't suitable for more complex deployments. For instance, database could accept connections but migrations aren't applyied yet.
2. Make container able to post own status in Consul/etcd. All dependent services will poll certain endpoint which contains status of needed service. Looks nice but seems redundant, don't it?
3. Manage startup order of containers by external scheduler.

Which of the approaches above are preferable in context of absence/presence orchestrators like Swarm/Kubernetes/etc in delivery process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can take a stab at the kubernetes perspective on those.

> Designing containers which are able to check the health of dependent services. Simple script whait-for-it can be useful for this kind of developing containers, but aren't suitable for more complex deployments. For instance, database could accept connections but migrations aren't applied yet.

This sounds like you want to differentiate between liveness and readiness. Kubernetes allows for [both types of probes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/production-pods/#liveness-and-readiness-probes-aka-health-checks) for these, that you can use to check health and wait before serving any traffic.

> Make container able to post own status in Consul/etcd. All dependent services will poll certain endpoint which contains status of needed service. Looks nice but seems redundant, don't it?

I agree. Having to maintain state separately is not preferred. However, in cases where it is absolutely necessary, if you really want to store the state of a resource, it is possible to use a [third party resource](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/thirdpartyresources/).

> Manage startup order of containers by external scheduler.

This seems tangential to the discussion mostly. However, [Pet Sets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/), soon to be replaced by Stateful Sets in Kubernetes v1.5, give you deterministic order of initialization of pods. For containers on a single pod, there are [init-containers](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/production-pods/#handling-initialization) which run serially and in order prior to running the main container.